# remove specific last characters using awk

Tags: awk

I need a single command to do the following  : Originial string is //abc/dd/ee/file_name.sv#25 eg I need to get the string ${ENV}/dd/ee/file_name.sv so I asssumed I would do an inital awk and use substring to strip //abc. Then wanted to follow up with removing the #25 and pre-pend the ${ENV}

Comment: are those strings in variable or in a file? Is that all thats in the file? Does it contain other text that has `#`s that you don't want to modify? Why do you need to use awk? Do you literally want to append the string `$ENV_VAR` or whatever `$ENV_VAR` expands to?

Comment: string is actually given on command line(we can assume they are in a variable) No, string has only 1 # and followed by a numerical value. I want to append $ENV_VAR expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
awk -F# -v env="$ENV" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NF > 1 { $NF = env } 1' filename
```

if the data is in a file, or

```
echo "$data" | awk -F# -v env="$ENV" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NF > 1 { $NF = env } 1'
```

if it is in a shell variable; it is not entirely clear to me which it is from the question.

This will split each line into fields at `#` and replace the last field with `$ENV` (known as `env` to the awk code because of `-v env="$ENV"`) before printing if there is more than one field (otherwise there was no `#` in the line). `OFS = FS` ensures that the output is separated the same way as the input.

Comment: I may be wrong (the question is unclear). But I think the OP wish the env at beginning of the string.

Comment: As I understood it, "prefix of the string" refers to the bit that's left after the bit at the end is removed, and `$ENV` should be appended to it. Hopefully OP will come back and clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need awk for this:

```
$ ENV_VAR="foo"
$ var="aaaaaaa#24"
$ echo "${var%#*}$ENV_VAR"
aaaaaaafoo
```

Comment: Ok. I didn't state my full requirement - I need a single command to do the following  : Originial string is //abc/dd/ee/file_name.sv#25 eg I need to get the string ${ENV}/dd/ee so I asssumed I would do an inital awk and use substring to strip //abc. Then wanted to follow up with removing the #25 and pre-pend the ${ENV}

Comment: You think you need to explain your question in full or you think I need to explain my answer in full? Don't try to add detail in a comment. Edit your question to provide all relevant information in that one location.